# Test cases logging increased number of kafka client connection issues after upgrading spring-kafka to 3.0.10

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, integration-testing, spring-kafka

We have a Spring Test, where we create a @MockBean of a Kafka template, so that the context doesn't fail to initialize during the startup. This is just a base class and does not have any tests in it other test classes extend it.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationTest.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class,
                webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestExecutionListeners(value = { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        FlywayTestExecutionListener.class },
                        mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("int")
public class IntegrationTestBase {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    User user;

    @MockBean
    private KafkaTemplate<UUID, SpecificRecord> avroTemplate;
}
```

So, when I try to launch/run a test class, it goes off to initialize the context and starts giving the error:

```
2023-11-27T17:50:30.154+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:30.271+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:30.272+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:30.380+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:30.380+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:30.600+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:30.601+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:31.040+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:31.041+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:31.909+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:31.909+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:33.110+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:33.110+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:34.315+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:34.315+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:35.409+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:35.410+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:36.285+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:36.286+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:37.156+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:37.157+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:38.360+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:38.360+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:39.236+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:39.237+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:40.440+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:40.440+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:41.639+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:41.639+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:42.731+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:42.733+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:43.715+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:43.715+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:44.589+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:44.589+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:45.796+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:45.796+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:46.891+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:46.891+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:48.097+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:48.098+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:49.191+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:49.192+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:50.168+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:50.169+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:51.255+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:51.256+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:52.457+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:52.458+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:53.662+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:53.662+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:54.648+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:54.649+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:55.745+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:55.745+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:56.729+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:56.729+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:57.707+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:57.708+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:58.583+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:58.584+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-11-27T17:50:59.558+05:30  INFO 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-27T17:50:59.559+05:30  WARN 5064 --- [ my-service] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=my-service] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

In the previous version of spring-kafka(2.7.14) we did not receive these many logs, this is also increasing the time it takes to execute these tests, where we only see this log getting printed only once in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After, looking at the logs, we found out that the issue was being caused as kafka was retrying multiple times to connect to a queue, which does not exist.
It was looking for the queue as we had setup a kafka-template mock bean which was required in order to get the context initialized properly.

We resolved the issue by setting this property for the test environment:
`spring.kafka.admin.auto-create=false`